# Firebase: permission_denied -- cannot access newData.child()

Tags: firebase

This is the structure of my data

```
{
 "projects" : {
     "proj1" : {
           "-JccS4StrTnJdTficR-u" : {
               "name" : "consultation",
               "status" : false
     },
          "-Jd6JlJUfyyZ2U0NTQEs" : {
               "name" : "Words",
               "status" : false
  }
   },
   "proj2" : {
          "-JccS6nwYHRrxvjZtCkt" : {
              "name" : "Rework",
              "status" : false
  },
         "-Jd6Jqa7-EPJuWxbtJAV" : {
             "name" : "Review",
             "status" : false
    }
   },
   "proj3" : {
         "-JccSJ5lEBQEg3XCbG-u" : {
            "name" : "translation",
            "status" : false
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

Here are my rules

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  "projects": {
      "proj1": {
        ".write": "auth != null"
      },
      "proj2": {
        ".write": true
      },
      "proj3": {
        ".write": true,
        ".validate": "newData.child('name').isString() 
                      && newData.child('name').val().length < 10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I created the database, there was no rule. Now, I've created the rules. I want the length of the name to be less than 10 characters.

When I run the code, I'm getting the following error: `FIREBASE WARNING: set at /projects/proj3/-Jd4n6XditTHLWKVmhC6 failed: permission_denied`

I can't exactly tell why it's not working. I've also tried just this portion `newData.child('name').isString()`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Here is the code that push data to FireBase

```
function saveToFB(taskName, proj) { 
  // this will save data to Firebase
  var project=projTasks.child(proj);
  project.push({
    name: taskName,
    status: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the structure of your data, as well as your rules, it looks like there is a missing level of data between "proj1"/"proj2"/"proj3" and the object that has `name` and `status` attributes.

Specifically, the `.validate` rules you have configured is checking the length of the `name` attribute for "proj3", not the new element added to the list there.

To get around this, try increasing the depth of the security rules definitions, and make use of the `$wildcard` functionality, where any security rules key prefixed with `$` is treated as a wildcard with a name that you can reuse.

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  "projects": {
      "proj1": {
        ".write": "auth != null"
      },
      "proj2": {
        ".write": true
      },
      "proj3": {
        ".write": true,
        "$someChildElementHere": {
          ".validate": "newData.child('name').isString() 
                        && newData.child('name').val().length < 10"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```